# How can I remove items from a LinkedList if a certain property appears several times?

Tags: java, addition

I have a LinkedList that is filled with objects of the type WebCacheEvents. Each object has attributes like description, event, label, lectureId, etc:

```
//filling the list with data received earlier
List<WebCacheEvents> result = new LinkedList<WebCacheEvents>();
                for (WebCache event : events) 
                    result.add(new thabella.dto.out.WebCacheEvents(event));
                return result;
```

What I want to do is to remove any WebCacheEvent that has a lectureId that is already used by another WebCacheEvent in the list - so that in my result every lectureId only appears once.

Therefore, I can't simply use

```
if(!result.contains(event))
    result.add(event);
```

because I am not really looking for real duplicates, where every attribute of the WebCacheEvent has the same value, but only for objects with the same lectureId. There can be two or more objects with the same lectureId in my received events.

Is there a similar way to use the "contains"-method but only for certain properties of an object?

Comment: If there are duplicates, how do you decide which one stays while the others go?

Comment: If there are events with the same lectureId, I just want to add the first event in the list and remove the other ones with identical lectureIds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
LinkedList<WebCacheEvents> result = new LinkedList<WebCacheEvents>();
if(!doesContain(result, event))
result.add(event); 

public boolean doesContain(LinkedList<Integer> result, WebCacheEvents obj) {
  boolean isContained = false;
  for (WebCacheEvents data : result){
    if (data.getLectureId() == obj.getLectureId()){
      isContained = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return isContained;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use simply a filter:

```
List<WebCacheEvents> result = new LinkedList<WebCacheEvents>();
    for (WebCache event : events)
        if (result.stream().noneMatch(w -> w.getLectureId().equals(event.getLectureId())))
            result.add(new thabella.dto.out.WebCacheEvents(event));
    return result;
```

I suppose lecturId cannot be null.

Comment: In fact you don't even need to call filter(), the stream gives access to a noneMatch() method directly to which you can pass the predicate.

Comment: @Gimby of course you are right. I have wrote that without IDE Support.

Comment: Thank you so much; I forgot to mention that I am not using Java8.